# Admob real ads not showing

Tags: android, admob

i am having problems in showing ads on my android app. I am able to show ads using this

```
AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().
        addTestDevice("127544499E3830865BD4E63234B4CC99").build();
        adview.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But when i wanted to show real ads, i removed this

```
 addTestDevice("127544499E3830865BD4E63234B4CC99")
```

but now its showing nothing, just plain white. So anybody have idea, i looked at another question but nothing works, everything this correct from my admob account and i am also having permissions,activity & meta in my manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the situation, this was happening because of the device it self. I mean only on that device later when i gave this a little time and tested it on other device. It just worked great.

Thanks everyone for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your logcat, it will tell you why you aren't showing any ads. It's probably because there aren't any to show right now. This is a normal situation.

Answer (score 0):

You have removed the ad id number so it has nothing to show. You are supposed to insert your number that you generated on admob page.
There is a tutorial: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start